# headerView does not scroll with the listview Android

Tags: android

I am using a DragSortListView and i want a header which will scroll down and up with the list. I have no idea why the header is not scrolling with the list. I use the listview in a fragment and i added the header like this:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    DragSortListView cursListView = (DragSortListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drag_list);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Utils.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    titleLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_row, null);

    cursListView.addHeaderView(titleLayout);

    setTitle(titleName, titleValue);

    cursListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);}
```

setTitle sets the values for the header and Utils.getContext() return the context of the Application.

```
public void setTitle(String currency, float value) {

    ((TextView) titleLayout.findViewById(R.id.titleName)).setText(currency);
    ((EditText) titleLayout.findViewById(R.id.titleValue)).setText(String.valueOf(value));

    ((EditText) titleLayout.findViewById(R.id.titleValue)).setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.convert), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    ((EditText) titleLayout.findViewById(R.id.titleValue)).setOnEditorActionListener(convertCurrencies);

    restartLoader();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create the illusion of a header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This way the TextView, in this case, will always stay on top, the ListView can still scroll, which is the desired result if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: well, this works for me but xml file is pretty ugly now..i am curios why the header didn't work properly

Comment: As is shortly described here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html, chapter 16.2, the headerView and footerView are a part of your listview as Jay was trying to tell you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25017667/1235505. Hence when you have a lot of items in your list, the footerView could not be visible since you would have to scroll down the list to see it. And when you've scrolled down the list, you cannot see the headerView anymore. So, HeaderView is the very first item in your list and FooterView is the very last item in your list, **They are a part of your list**.

Comment: **when the list gets scrolled, the HeaderView and FooterView could not be visible**

Answer (score 0):

i think you have first understand what is Header of Footer. Header means that is Always on Top and visible in any Condition same as Footer which is always on bottom and visible.that same concept use for HeaderView and FooterView in listview in android.

So Achive your goal Add one item as header and get it in your Adapterclass getView method and Display it. if there are only one header then at 0 position Your Header available and other position your item available. and it is scroll with your list.

Thats it...

Comment: how can i add header from CursorAdapter? i am new in Android that's why i ask so many questions

Comment: you have use BaseAdapter and create your own CustomAdapter using BaseAdapter. see this :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/